# Sparse × Sparse matrix product which computes only some its elements

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose `A`, `B` and `C` are sparse matrices in any format. And I wonder how to compute their dot product efficiently only for elements which are nonzero in `C`.

It's equal to

```
prod = A.dot(B)
prod[C == 0] = 0
```

for dense matrices in Python. But this code is extremely inefficient.

Could you please advise me something? Memory doesn't matter.

Comment: Why not using numpy ?

Comment: @rak007 numpy dense matrices multiplication is too expensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast `C` to boolean and take advantage of the fact that the value `True` will become `1` in the context of multiplication. You can then do element wise multiplication between the product of `A.dot(B)` and `C`.

You can achieve that by:

```
A.dot(B).to_csr().multiple(C.to_csr())
```

### Faster Dot Product

In order to get the fastest possible dot product I would brute search over all sparse formats offered by `scipy`. Define a timing function such as :

```
from functools import wraps
from time import time

def timing(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time()
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time()
        print 'Elapsed time: {}'.format(end-start)
        return result
    return wrapper

@timing
def csr_dot(a, b):
    # Write similar functions for all other formats
    return a.to_csr().dot(b.to_csr())

# This will print some time. Repeat for other formats.
csr_dot(A, B)
```

You can then choose the format that yielded the best time.

Comment: It sounds like a good solution, thanks! But if there is a way to carry out this operation faster than `A.dot(B)` it would be great.

Comment: I added my thoughts on optimizing the dot product calculation in the answer.